# Finding size of a block number

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, javascript, etherscan

Below is a simple programme which includes web3 :-

```
let web3 = require('web3');
var real = new web3(web3.givenProvider)    //  web3.givenProvider is having value of my infura endpoint

discuss();

async function discuss()
 {
let dif = await real.eth.getBlock(16532022)
let di = dif.size
console.log(di)             //    Line 1 :- displays the size

console.log(typeof dif )    // Line 2 :- returns object  

let   diftwo = await real.eth.getBlock(16532022).size ;

console.log(diftwo) ;    // Line 3 :- displays undefined
```

When I used the `.size` directly in Line 3 it is not showing the size of block. I checked the `typeof` of the `.getBlock` and saw that it is an object  which means `size` is  key of that object. So why is it not showing the  result when I used the `size` using the dot notation.

Below code works

```
let   diftwo = (await real.eth.getBlock(16532022)).size ;  // associating await with .getblock
console.log(diftwo) ;
```

But in this manner , system has to fetch entire block info and  then go to size property. Suppose if I have to get the size of numerous block  for some use-case then waiting for fetching of entire block info will be too cumbersome. That is why , I am trying somehow trying that `await`  should not get associated.

Can anyone please tell me the mistake which I am doing in `Line 3`.

Comment: just a small comment: a blockis made of a `Header`, `Transactions` and `Receipts`. These 3 pieces make a complete block that can be exported or imported by `geth` . After you implement your functionality to get the block size via RPC, please verify the size versus the same block number, but exported via "export" command. The block data is RLP encoded, so it is a long string of hexadecimal values and it contains everything, one line per block inside the export-file.

Comment: it is just a suggestion to implement quality assurance for your code

Answer (score 2):

Hi Developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here

You are really close to finding out the answer.

DL,DR
The first time, you are getting `size` attribute from a `block` object. the second time, you are getting the `size` attribute from `eth.getBlock()`.

Basically, `web3.eth.getBlock()` is a [asynchronous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing). It returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) when it is created.
After a promise is "resolved" - meaning finish running and get the result from RPC provider(**btw Chainstack is a good RPC provider too**)- it becomes a block object, which contains the "size" attribute.
`await` keyword before a promise lets your script pause and wait for the result.

The second time you call `web3.eth.getBlock().size`. Here you are trying to get `size` from a promise, instead of a block object.

`web3.eth.getBlock().size` is syntactically correct but of course, there is no such attribute before it is resolved, so It is `undefined`. in this case, the `await` keyword doesn't do anything.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So means as per you  , `(await real.eth.getBlock(16532022)).size` is the solution ?